# RStudio 'Fatal error' when running Motif analysis - Troubleshooting advice needed

Tags: r, crash

The following code causes RStudio Desktop on my system to crash and I have no idea why. This code was running without problems about 9 months ago using older versions of R and RStudio.

```
library("MotIV")
library("org.Dm.eg.db")
library("MotifDb")


# Get all fly gene entrezID from within org.Dm.eg.db
  entrez_fly <- keys(org.Dm.eg.db)

# Grab FBgn from org.Dm.eg.db
  FBgn_entrez <- mapIds(org.Dm.eg.db, keys=entrez_fly, column="ENSEMBL", keytype="ENTREZID", multiVals="first")
# Remove non-match entries (NAs)
  FBgn_entrez <- FBgn_entrez[!is.na(FBgn_entrez)]
# Also get FBgn <-> Symbol pairs
  Symbol_FBgn <- mapIds(org.Dm.eg.db, keys=FBgn_entrez, column="SYMBOL", keytype="ENSEMBL", multiVals="first")
  refseq_entrez <- toTable(org.Dm.egREFSEQ[entrez_fly])

# e.g. 'Hand'
  Hand_motifdb <- query(MotifDb, 'ZEB1')
# @listData extracts a list of all TFBS in motifdb for this gene
  Hand_motifs <- Hand_motifdb@listData

  x <- motifMatch(Hand_motifs[1], as.list (MotifDb), top=10)
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] MotifDb_1.30.0       Biostrings_2.56.0    XVector_0.28.0       org.Dm.eg.db_3.11.4  AnnotationDbi_1.50.3 Biobase_2.48.0      
 [7] MotIV_1.43.0         GenomicRanges_1.40.0 GenomeInfoDb_1.24.2  IRanges_2.22.2       S4Vectors_0.26.1     BiocGenerics_0.34.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] SummarizedExperiment_1.18.2 tinytex_0.26                tidyselect_1.1.0            xfun_0.18                  
 [5] purrr_0.3.4                 lattice_0.20-41             vctrs_0.3.4                 generics_0.0.2             
 [9] rtracklayer_1.48.0          blob_1.2.1                  XML_3.99-0.5                rlang_0.4.8                
[13] pillar_1.4.6                glue_1.4.2                  DBI_1.1.0                   BiocParallel_1.22.0        
[17] bit64_4.0.5                 splitstackshape_1.4.8       matrixStats_0.57.0          GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.3     
[21] lifecycle_0.2.0             plyr_1.8.6                  zlibbioc_1.34.0             zip_2.1.1                  
[25] memoise_1.1.0               Rcpp_1.0.5                  rGADEM_2.36.0               BSgenome_1.56.0            
[29] seqLogo_1.54.3              DelayedArray_0.14.1         bit_4.0.4                   Rsamtools_2.4.0            
[33] digest_0.6.26               stringi_1.5.3               openxlsx_4.2.2              dplyr_1.0.2                
[37] grid_4.0.2                  tools_4.0.2                 bitops_1.0-6                magrittr_1.5               
[41] RCurl_1.98-1.2              tibble_3.0.4                RSQLite_2.2.1               crayon_1.3.4               
[45] pkgconfig_2.0.3             ellipsis_0.3.1              Matrix_1.2-18               data.table_1.13.2          
[49] rstudioapi_0.11             R6_2.4.1                    GenomicAlignments_1.24.0    compiler_4.0.2
```

At this point, I have no idea where to find an issue. RStudio's log file does not contain complaints/issues. It just crashes.

EDIT:
The libraries can be installed with these lines:
First, Bioconductor:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.11")
```

Then, the libraries:

```
BiocManager::install(c("MotIV", "org.Dm.eg.db", "MotifDb"))
```

EDIT 2: Tested with R (plain) and get the following error:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x2, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

Comment: None of these packages are available on CRAN. How would we be able to reproduce?

Comment: It crashed R for me as well. I would let the package maintainers know about this issue.